# Microsoft Cognitive Service fails in Azure (trainingApi fails in Azure when instantiated)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Cognitive.CustomVision.Training/1.2.0 on my website.

I using the library to create a new object of TrainingApi like this:

```
new TrainingApi() {ApiKey = "<API key>"};
```

This works fine on locally but when published and running in Azure I get this error:

> Method not found: 'Void
>   Microsoft.Cognitive.CustomVision.Training.TrainingApi..ctor(System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[])'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Void
>   Microsoft.Cognitive.CustomVision.Training.TrainingApi..ctor(System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[])'.

Has anyone any experience with this or know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm just curious, what's your solution structure like? Do you have multiple projects in it?

Comment: @Jon yes I have multiple projects. The project where I get this error is separate from the web project.

Comment: Perhaps it may help if you have the `CustomVision.Training` package installed on each project?